# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error while displaying it in bar graph

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/madhav ji/Downloads/tips (1).csv')
#print('Number of all the countries:',len(df),'\n')
#print(df.head(5),'\n')
tip=df.tip
#print(tip.head(5),'\n')
tip_mean=tip.mean()
#print(tip_mean,'\n')
gen=df.groupby(['sex'])['tip']
#print(gen)
plt.bar(gen,tip_mean)
```

getting below error while plotting a bar graph

other sites suggests and its a issue in numpy array but i am not using any type of array here

gives below error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: Please post the error's full stack trace.

Comment: Please share some sample data from the CSV file.

Comment: total_bill tip sex smoker day time size
16.99 1.01 Female No Sun Dinner 2
10.34 1.66 Male No Sun Dinner 3
21.01 3.5 Male No Sun Dinner 3
23.68 3.31 Male No Sun Dinner 2
24.59 3.61 Female No Sun Dinner 4
25.29 4.71 Male No Sun Dinner 4
8.77 2 Male No Sun Dinner 2
26.88 3.12 Male No Sun Dinner 4
15.04 1.96 Male No Sun Dinner 2
14.78 3.23 Male No Sun Dinner 2
10.27 1.71 Male No Sun Dinner 2
35.26 5 Female No Sun Dinner 4
15.42 1.57 Male No Sun Dinner 2
18.43 3 Male No Sun Dinner 4
14.83 3.02 Female No Sun Dinner 2
21.58 3.92 Male No Sun Dinner 2

Comment: i need to find out:Calculate average tip by the following groups and visualize the same using bar charts (use subplots) 

Gender